# How to get src/main/java classloader from unit test

Tags: java, reflection, junit

In a unit test, I'm trying to get a list of classes under a package.

When I do

```
...getClassLoader().getResource("<some package in both main and test>");
```

from a unit test, it returns a URL that points to `test-classes`. How do I get the URL to the main classes?

**EDIT:**

To be clearer, I am after a classloader that gives me access to the main classes. Ultimately, to get the right URL.

Comment: ClassLoader shows you from where the java classes were loaded. to get a url that points to main classes the loader must be used in main classes

Comment: I know. And how to do that from a unit test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ClassLoader.getResource returns the first URL it found. Try getResources() it will search on all available classpathes

Comment: Thanks. I missed that method, doh!